# how to report grammar ambiguity in antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

According to the antlr4 book (page 159), and using the grammar Ambig.g4, grammar ambiguity can be reported by:

```
grun Ambig stat -diagnostics
```

or equivalently, in code form:

```
parser.removeErrorListeners();
parser.addErrorListener(new DiagnosticErrorListener());
parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION);
```

The grun command reports the ambiguity properly for me, using **antlr-4.5.3**. But when I use the code form, I dont get the ambiguity report. Here is the command trace:

```
$ antlr4 Ambig.g4   # see the book's page.159 for the grammar
$ javac Ambig*.java
$ grun Ambig stat -diagnostics < in1.txt # in1.txt is as shown on page.159
    line 1:3 reportAttemptingFullContext d=0 (stat), input='f();'
    line 1:3 reportAmbiguity d=0 (stat): ambigAlts={1, 2}, input='f();'
$ javac TestA_Listener.java
$ java TestA_Listener < in1.txt   # exits silently
```

The TestA_Listener.java code is the following:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.*; // for PredictionMode
import java.util.*;
public class TestA_Listener {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        AmbigLexer lexer = new AmbigLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        AmbigParser parser = new AmbigParser(tokens);
        parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener
        parser.addErrorListener(new DiagnosticErrorListener());
        parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION);
        parser.stat();
    }
}
```

Can somebody please point out how the above java code should be modified, to print the ambiguity report?

For completeness, here is the code Ambig.g4 :

grammar Ambig;

```
stat: expr ';'        // expression statement
    | ID '(' ')' ';'  // function call statement
    ;

expr: ID '(' ')'
    | INT
    ;

INT :   [0-9]+ ;
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;
WS  :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

And here is the input file in1.txt :

```
f();
```

Answer (score 1):

Antlr4 is a top-down parser, so for the given input, the parse match is unambiguously:

`stat` -> `expr` -> `ID` -> `(` -> `)` -> `stat(cnt'd)` -> `;`

The second `stat` alt is redundant and never reached, not ambiguous.

To resolve the apparent redundancy, a predicate might be used:

```
stat: e=expr {isValidExpr($e)}? ';'   #exprStmt
    | ID '(' ')' ';'                  #funcStmt
    ;
```

When `isValidExpr` is false, the function statement alternative will be evaluated.

Comment: I understand how to fix an ambiguity/redundancy, but my question was different. I had asked, how to get an ambiguity/redundancy report from antlr? Once I know that a particular rule is ambiguous/redundant, I can go and fix it. "grun -diagnostics" provides this ambiguity/redundancy report, but how to get this report using java code?

Answer (score 1):

I waited for several days for other people to post their answers. Finally after several rounds of experimenting, I found an answer:

The following line should be deleted from the above code. Then we get the same ambiguity report as given by grun.

```
parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener
```

Comment: I'm trying that very tutorial right now, and this fix no longer works. It seems Antlr now resolves that grammar unambiguously. Not the first time the book hasn't matched the library; but it has gone through several 4.X versions since 2013. That being said, it might be time for a new version of the book... And I think this grammar should be reported as ambiguous. Final caveat: I'm using C#

Comment: @NarftheMouse: I dont understand why you said that, because I ran with versions 4.6 and 4.7, and grun (and the above java code) reported the same ambiguities. There is no way this grammar ambiguity can be resolved automatically by the antlr tool, the only way is to add predicates as answered by GRosenberg.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will be work

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CharStream input = CharStreams.fromStream(System.in);
    AmbigLexer lexer = new AmbigLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    AmbigParser parser = new AmbigParser(tokens);
    //parser.removeErrorListeners(); // remove ConsoleErrorListener
    parser.addErrorListener(new org.antlr.v4.runtime.DiagnosticErrorListener());  // add ours
    parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION);
    parser.stat(); // parse as usual
}
```